# prove that $\log x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (x-1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis

**prove that**  $\;\log x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (x-1)^n$

My attempt:$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (x-1)^n=(x-1)-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{3}(x-1))^3+....$

$\log (1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+........$

put 1+x=t$\rightarrow $x=t-1

$\log t=t-1-\frac{(t-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(t-1)^3}{3}+.................$ Is this right

how we going to processed this problem i did't get any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $f(x)$ be represented as the series

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}(x-1)^n=\frac{1}{x}$$

for $|x-1|<1$.  Now, integrate term by term.

Comment: This is a clear but recursive answer since the topic starter can ask: "How to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}(x-1)^n=\frac{1}{x}$"

Comment: @caran-d'ache I assume that if one is pursuing the series for the logarithm function, then one knows how to sum a geometric series.